# Custom Index Section List Positioning

Tags: ios, uitableview, indexing

I've implemented a custom index section list by programmatically adding buttons using a loop. Here is the code in my table view controller:

```
int offset = 65;
int yposition = 40;
NSString *letter;
for (int i=0; i<26; i++) 
{
    letter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",offset];
    UIButton *a = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [a setAlpha:0.7];
    a.frame = CGRectMake(300,yposition,20,15);
    [a setTitle:letter forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [a addTarget:self action:@selector(pressedIndex:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.parentViewController.view addSubview:a];
    offset += 1;
    yposition += 15;
}
```

It works fine, except when I go back to the parent view, which the index list is still present on. And that makes sense. If I hard my index list buttons directly the table view, then when the user scrolls down the table view, the buttons scrolls down and disappear.

Any suggestion as to how I could have my buttons position persist on the screen?

Thank you.

Comment: I ended up using a UIView ivar, adding it to the parentViewController, adding my index list buttons to it, and remove the UIView ivar from the parentViewController in -(void)viewWillDisappear. But now, the issue is that clicking on the buttons doesn't trigger the actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a nib file, adding a view in IB, and programmatically adding my index list buttons to that view.